# Test class code is not covering

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
public class TaskTriggerActions {

public static void RecentSurvey(List<Task> lTask) {

    Set<Id> completedIds = new Set<Id>();
    list<Task> scoredTasks = new list<Task>();
    list<Task> listtask = new list<Task>();

    for(Task record: lTask) {
       scoredTasks.add(record);
            completedIds.add(record.WhoId);
        }

    if(scoredTasks.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Map<Id, Id> contactToSurveys = new Map<Id, Id>();
    list<Id> records = new list<Id>();
     system.debug('Mapofid++++++ '+contactToSurveys );
    for(Survey__c srecord: [SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Survey__c WHERE  Contact__c IN :completedIds order by CreatedDate desc limit 1]) {
        system.debug('survrey+++++ '+srecord);
        records.add(srecord.id); 
        contactToSurveys.put(srecord.Id,srecord.Contact__c);
        system.debug('List of Surveys: '+contactToSurveys);
    }
    if(records.Size>0){
    for(Task record1: scoredTasks) {
        record1.whatId= records[0];     
        system.debug('whatid++++' + record1.whatId);   
    }
    }
}
}
```

The Test class which i developed for above class is executing, But not even single line is covering. I can't figured out the problem

```
     @IsTest
  public class TaskTriggerActionsTest  {  
 static testMethod void RecentsurveyTest() {

 pse_resource__GeoLocationSettings__c glSettings = new pse_resource__GeoLocationSettings__c();
    glSettings.pse_resource__Resource_Request_Trigger_Disabled__c = true;
    glSettings.pse_resource__Resource_Trigger_Disabled__c = true;
    upsert glSettings;

    glSettings = new pse_resource__GeoLocationSettings__c();
    glSettings.setupOwnerId = Userinfo.getUserId();
    glSettings.pse_resource__Resource_Request_Trigger_Disabled__c = true;
    glSettings.pse_resource__Resource_Trigger_Disabled__c = true;
    upsert glSettings;

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new wwwBoomiCalloutMock());

    //Create test data for User
    User usr1 = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestUser(1, UserInfo.getProfileId());
    insert usr1;
    //Create test data for Managers
    User mgrusr1 = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestUser(2, UserInfo.getProfileId());
    insert mgrusr1;
    //Assign Manager to User
    usr1.ManagerID = mgrusr1.Id;
    update usr1;

 system.runAs(usr1){ 
        //Create test data for Account
        Account acc = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestAccount(1);
        insert acc;
        //create test contact
        Contact con = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestContact(1);
        insert con;   

     survey__c survey = new survey__c(Contact__c = con.id);
     Insert survey;

     test.startTest();

     Task task= new task();
     task.Subject='Message Sent';
    task.status='Completed';
    task.Whatid= survey.id;
    insert task;

     test.stopTest();

 }        

 }
}
```

do i need to pass class instance or anything in Test.startTest() and  Test.StopTest(). Can any one please help me

Trigger Handler:

```
             public class TaskTriggerHandler {
             //variable declaration
              private boolean m_isExecuting = false;
              private integer BatchSize = 0;

            //constructor
              public TaskTriggerHandler(boolean isExecuting, integer size){
                m_isExecuting = isExecuting;
                BatchSize = size;
            }

             public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Task> triggerNew){   

             TaskTriggerActions.RecentSurvey(triggerNew);
            }//end of before Insert

            public void OnAfterInsert(List<Task> triggerNew){    
            }//end of after Insert

            public void OnBeforeUpdate(List<Task> triggerNew){    
            }//end of before Update

            public void OnAfterUpdate(List<Task> triggerNew){    
            }//end of after Update

            }
```

trigger:

```
            trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert,after insert,before update,after update) {

            Trigger_Controls__c CS = Trigger_Controls__c.getOrgDefaults();
            if(CS.Task_Trigger__c){// trigger toggle
                TaskTriggerHandler handler = new TaskTriggerHandler (Trigger.isExecuting, Trigger.size);
                 //Runs on before insert only
                if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {    
                    handler.OnBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
                }//e
                //Runs on after insert only
                if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {    
                    handler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
                }//end of after insert condition

                //Runs on before update only 
                if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {    
                    handler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.new);
                }//end of before update condition

                    //Runs on after update only 
               //  if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {  
               //              handler.OnAfterUpdate(trigger.new,trigger.old,trigger.newMap,trigger.oldMap);
               //}//end of afte update condition
             }// end of trigger toggle

               }
```

Comment: Is this class being called from a trigger? If so can you post the trigger code as well?

Comment: Hi @highfive I've updated the my question can please any suggestions ?

Comment: Try putting some debug statements in trigger if block, `OnBeforeInsert` of handler class and finally in `RecentSurvey` of `RecentSurvey` class to check whether they are hitting. What's he purpose of `m_isExecuting`? Is that avoiding some classes being executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is an easy omission to make

Custom Settings (List and Hierarchical) need to be mocked in testmethods

Your trigger has a master execute switch:

```
Trigger_Controls__c CS = Trigger_Controls__c.getOrgDefaults();
if(CS.Task_Trigger__c) { 
     // do the work
}
```

but you never mock the `Trigger_Controls__c` in the test method so `CS.Task_Trigger__c` will be false. You mocked other settings, just not this one.

*as an aside, these kind of master switches are best named like `Are_Task_Triggers_Enabled__c` as `Task_Trigger__c` can be interpreted as a noun rather than a condition*

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I just made it true and ran. Got enough code coverage. Thank you very much.